# jq print parent name, values, and children values

Tags: json, jq

I'm new to jq, but I'm confident it can help my workflow once I figure it out. I have been provided with some data that looks something like the below:

```
{
  "parent_name1": {
    "parent_count": 2000, 
    "fields": {
      "field1_count": 2000, 
      "field2_count": 2000,
      ...
      "fieldx_count": 20
    }
  }, 
  "parent_name2": {
    "parent_count": 1000, 
    "fields": {
      "field1_count": 1000, 
      "field2_count": 1000,
      ...
      "fieldx_count": 100
    }
  },
  "parent_namex": {
    ...
  }
}
```

There are two things I want to do:

1. Select a specific parent name and have it display the name and all children values (count, and all field counts).
2. Show all parent names where field counts are less than the total parent count.

I am close with the below commands, but they still aren't quite where I want them to be:

```
jq '."parent_name1"'
```

will give me "parent_count", "fields" and all of the field counts, but does not provide the parent name.

This:

```
jq '.[] | {parent_count: .parent_count, fields: .fields[]} | select(.fields < .parent_count)'
```

returns "parent_count" and a total field count, but not the parent name or the counts for the individual fields. I know the summed field count comes from `{fields: .fields[]}`, but I cannot find any way to get even remotely close to what I want without that.

Comment: Does this work for #1?

`$ jq '{"parent_name1" : getpath(["parent_name1"])}' /tmp/foo.json`
{
  "parent_name1": {
    "parent_count": 2000,
    "fields": {
      "field1_count": 2000,
      "field2_count": 2000,
      "fieldx_count": 20
    }
  }
}

Answer (score 3):

As you have noticed, using

```bsh
jq '.parent_name2' file
```

or, with the section's name given as a parameter,

```bsh
jq --arg parent 'parent_name2' '.[$parent]' file
```

would not output a JSON object with `parent_name2` as the top-level key.

However, we may *create* an object with the needed data:

```bsh
$ jq --arg parent 'parent_name2' '{($parent): .[$parent]}' file
```

Given a sanitized variant of your example document, this would produce

```json
{
  "parent_name2": {
    "parent_count": 1000,
    "fields": {
      "field1_count": 1000,
      "field2_count": 1000,
      "fieldx_count": 100
    }
  }
}
```

In your second query (only a single query per question in the future please), you presumably ask about the top-level key names corresponding to objects whose `.parent_count` value is less than the sum of the corresponding `.fields` counts.

```bsh
jq -r 'del(.[] | select(.parent_count >= (.fields | add ))) | keys[]' file
```

This *deletes* all sections where the sum of the `.fields` values are greater or equal to the `.parent_count` value.  It then extracts the top-level key names of all sections that are left.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response! And my apologies for having two queries, I'll be sure to only include one in future questions.

The first query you provided works great, thank you!
For the second query, would it be possible to have it also output the relevant field counts? (i.e. for each remaining parent_name also list the parent_count and field_counts? This would allow me to know exactly which fields I need to investigate.